# How can I remove just the writable files in a directory, without any prompt?

Tags: shell-script, rm

I want to delete only the writable files in a directory. If I do

```
rm *
```

it removes all the writable files (so far so good), but I get a prompt for each non-writable file. I don't want a prompt, I just want to leave the non-writable files alone.

The answer isn't 'rm -f', because that will remove the non-writable files.

So, is there simple command to remove *just* the writable files, without getting any prompts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `rm` will do this on its own, there's no obvious flag in the options.

You could use a mixture of `find` and `rm` to achieve it.

`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -writable -exec rm {} +`

For example,

```
tony@trinity:~/temp$ ls -l
total 0
tony@trinity:~/temp$ touch bob
tony@trinity:~/temp$ touch bill
tony@trinity:~/temp$ touch fred
tony@trinity:~/temp$ chmod 400 fred
tony@trinity:~/temp$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 bill
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 bob
-r-------- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 fred
tony@trinity:~/temp$ mkdir test
tony@trinity:~/temp$ cd test
tony@trinity:~/temp/test$ touch chris
tony@trinity:~/temp/test$ cd ..
tony@trinity:~/temp$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 20:19 bill
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 20:19 bob
-r-------- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 20:19 fred
drwxr-xr-x 2 tony tony 4096 Mar 10 20:19 test

./test:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 chris
tony@trinity:~/temp$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -writable -exec rm {} +
tony@trinity:~/temp$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
-r-------- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 20:19 fred
drwxr-xr-x 2 tony tony 4096 Mar 10 20:19 test

./test:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 chris
```

This won't behave the same as `rm -r` so you'll need to rethink it if you want to descend into subdirectories, and as written, it won't remove directories at all.

As [@Giles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) suggests, you can also use the `-delete` action to do all the work inside the `find`, for example,

```
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 23:16 bill
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 23:16 bob
-r-------- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 20:19 fred
drwxr-xr-x 2 tony tony 4096 Mar 10 20:19 test

./test:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 chris
tony@trinity:~/temp$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -writable -delete
tony@trinity:~/temp$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
-r-------- 1 tony tony    0 Mar 10 20:19 fred
drwxr-xr-x 2 tony tony 4096 Mar 10 20:19 test

./test:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 0 Mar 10 20:19 chris
```

Comment: You could use `-delete` instead of invoking `rm`. AFAIK all `find` implementations that have `-writable` also have `-delete`.

Comment: With `-type f`, you're only removing _regular_ files, not the other types of file. If you want to exclude directories, it should be `! -type d`, not `-type f`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *; do [ ! -w "$f" ] || rm -- "$f"; done
```

Or with `&&` instead of `||`:

```
[ -w "$f" ] && rm -- "$f"
```

(I prefer `||` as I use `set -e` a lot and a bare, unsuccessful `&&` clause will cause an exit in that mode)

Comment: That would fail to remove symlinks that point to files you don't have write access to.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
rm -- *(@,^/e:'[ -w $REPLY ]':)
```

That is, remove symlinks and non-directories (`rm` wouldn't remove them anyway, so we might as well exclude them) for which you have write access. Note that the `w` glob qualifier can't be used here as it only checks whether the file is writable by its owner (which may not be you).